# decline duplicate input (java)

Tags: java, eclipse

beginner here. I have a code for an auction and I want to be able to decline or print out an error for a dog that has already been put in the auction.

```
private void startAuction() {

    boolean current = false;
    int auctionCount = 1;

    do {
        System.out.println("Dog name: ");
        String dogName = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

        if(dogName.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Error: Name can't be empty.");
            continue;           
            }

    for (int i = 0; i < dogs.size(); i++) {
        if (dogName.equals(dogs.get(i).getName())) {
            auction.add(new Auction(dogName));

            System.out.printf(dogName + " has been put up for auction in auction #%d", auctionCount);
            System.out.println();
            auctionCount++;                

            current = true;
            return;

        }else if (auction.get(i).getDogName().equals(dogName)) {
            System.out.print("Error: Dog has already been put up for auction");
        }
    }
        if (current == false) {
            System.out.println("Error: no such dog in the register");

        }

    }while(true);
```

The rest of it works fine except for this part:

`}else if (auction.get(i).getDogName().equals(dogName)) {
    System.out.print("Error: Dog has already been put up for auction");`

I don't really know why but it just ignores all the duplicate inputs. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure they're really duplicate values?  No extra whitespace or unprintable characters?  I'd suggest stepping through your program in a debugger and checking what values you are actually comparing.

Comment: To pile on @azurefrog, this is a classic opportunity to use the debugger and examine the contents of dogName and the list of dogs you are searching.

Comment: @azurefrog yeah, I'm meant to print-out "error" when the user inputs the same name

Comment: You could use a `HashSet` to detect duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator i is for the dogs array, but in the "else if", you're using auction.get(i).  Is that meant to be dogs.get(i)?

Comment: no, I'm meant to check the auction list if the name of the dog is  already there. Thats why I used auction.get(i)

Comment: Sorry, I said that awkwardly.  Let me try to rephrase...so you're iterating through all your dogs with this:

for (int i = 0; i < dogs.size(); i++) {

and 'i' is the variable keeping track of your place in that iteration.  When you reference the auction, you're using 'i'...but I believe that's only relevant to the dogs array.  Could that be part of the issue?